# How to return a value from .ashx file to javascript in a variable

Tags: javascript, httphandler, ashx

I am calling ashx file from javascript.
Http Handler file returns string value.

```
context.response.write(string value);


<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){

$('area').each(function () {       
    var area = $(this),

alt = area.attr('id');
if (alt != null) {

                area.mouseenter(function () {
                    $('#dhtmltooltip').load("Search_CS.ashx?q=" +alt);
                    ddrivetip('', 300);
                }).mouseleave(function () {
                    $('#dhtmltooltip').html('');
                    hideddrivetip();
                });
            }

        });
```

I have to receive this string in  a variable in javascript.

How this can be done?

Comment: do you control the HttpHandler? What content-type is it setting/returning?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not making any ajax requests. Does this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904118/json-post-data-is-empty/5904246#5904246) help?
There is a function call named "insertCustomerCallback" which will have the html returned from the handler. There you need to write your code.
For e.g.,

```
function insertCustomerCallback(html) {
//write your code
}
```